# change working directory to one located on a different volume in cmd

Tags: cmd, dos, working-directory

In the command prompt I am able to change the working directory by typing CD "new path"

for example take a look on how I am able to select directories that are located in my C drive:

[image]

but note that when I select a directory located in a different volume (A:...) the command prompt will not change the working directory...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cd /d A:\Users` does what your looking for.

Comment: To explain this a bit further - there's a working directory for each drive, all saved independently. `cd A:\Users` changes the working directory for `A:` to that directory, but doesn't change your working drive to `A`.  If you did `cd A:\Users`, then `A:`, you'd find yourself in `A:\Users`.